# How do I grab the last portion of a log string and interpret it as json?

Tags: python, json, regex

I am looking at a log message with the following format

```
datetime log_message_type message_type server {json_string}
```

So each line is separated by whitespace, always has the same fields for each line, and at the end has a json string with a variety of fields inside the json block.

I thought about doing this with a simple

```
with open('test.log', 'r') as f:
    for x in f:
        line = x.split()

        datetime         = line[0]
        log_message_type = line[1]
        message_type     = line[2]
        server           = line[3]
        json_string      = line[4]
```

This would have worked, except there are spaces in my json string, for example, something like this.

```
{ "foo" : "bar" }
```

So doing it in this way would split up my json string at the spaces. Is there any way I could use a regex or something to split on whitespace only until I get to the "json string" section of the line, and then preserve the rest of it? I tried doing something like

```
line = re.compile(".*\s.*\s.*\s.*\s").split(x)
```

To attempt to parse the line based on the 4 spaces before the json string portion, but I'm afraid I just don't know enough about how the regex system in python works. Could anyone give me a hand?

Edit : forgot to mention, I'm stuck with python 2.7 for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like this. Regular expressions can quickly get out of hand.

```
log_line = "datetime log_message_type message_type server {json_string}"
json_part = log_line.split(None, 4)[-1]
```

Comment: thinking I'm gonna give this one the accept, seems the most concise and workable with python 2

Comment: thanks for this. This was the most workable given my python 2.7 constraints.

Comment: You're very welcome. The snippet works on Python 3 too.

Answer (score 6):

limit the number of splits:

```
line = x.split(maxsplit=4)

>>> "a b c d my json expression".split(maxsplit=4)
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'my json expression']
```

Note: python 2 arguments differ, you'd have to pass then as positional (also works with python 3 BTW):

```
line = x.split(None,4)
```

Comment: It should be 4 not 3

Comment: yes, fixed. I put 4 at first, then 3, but reading the question again, it's 4

Comment: only for python 3  I am assuming? :(

Comment: "split takes no keyword arguments"

Answer (score 2):

If you're using python 3 you can take advantage of [extended iterable unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/).

```
long_string = "example example test test test test test test"
x1, x2, *tests = long_string.split()
tests = ' '.join(tests)
print(tests)
#test test test test test test
```

Comment: problem with that approach is when `long_string = "example example test test test test 'test       test'"`: you destroy the information withing the quoted string by joining back with only _one_ space. The quickfix would be to do `long_string.split(" ")` (one space only) so joining back is bijective.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this?

```
line = "datetime log_message_type message_type server {json_string}" 

re.search(r"(\S+) (\S+) (\S+) (\S+) {(\S+)}", line).groups()
```

output:

```
('datetime', 'log_message_type', 'message_type', 'server', 'json_string')
```

Comment: NoneType has no element groups

Comment: I have edited my answer. I used it on this sample string.

Comment: using python 2.7 or 3+?

Comment: used python 3.5

Comment: same result for me unfortunately. I'm using 2.7 though

Comment: Must be only working with Python 3. Sorry I couldn't help :(

Comment: Regexps are often brittle because of how accurate they are. While it's possible (and not too hard) to get a right regexp to do the parsing, I've found that it's much more robust to do simple text manipulation if that serves your purposes.